# Css overflow:scroll does not work on mobile

Tags: android, html, css, mobile-browser

I have a website and I want to display comments in a div. I tried to use an overflow scroll div but it overflowed on mobile devices. It does work on my computer What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Scrolls for me in Mobile Safari.  Maybe post some code.

Comment: @thingEvery Strange cuz for me and my frirnds who use Android, it does not scroll.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling - Non-standard: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add this css code to your container with overflow scroll.

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: I can't add a comment yet until I reach 50 reputation.

Comment: #rightbox form { width: 500px; overflow: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; }

Comment: `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:  touch` is invalid property value

Comment: Works great in Chrome for Moto G5 Plus Android 8.1.0 (+1).

Answer (score 1):

How i solved that,
i strugled a lot and finally
i put in html css media query next code

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  html {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;
    max-width: 100vw !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
  }
  html ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Dont use -webkit-overflow-scrolling:  touch; !

In yours case make similar media query for your div element and adjust values by yours requirements.

I hope will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it!

```css
overflow-y: scroll !important;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Answer (score 0):

overflow: scroll;  // this property will work on mobile devices for scroll instead of ove

Answer (score 0):

using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` is the correct solution but it invalid in react, next you would need to use `WebkitOverflowScrolling: "touch"`